# Dealing with "The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted" error after timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have my asp.net MVC app throwing a "The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted" error while trying to login in a very particular situation that I didn't find anyone post on SO.

The error only happens when the login page is already opened for some minutes.

**Situation A - Everything works fine**: I load the login page, fill the username/password immediately, and press login button.

**Situation B - Throw "The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted" error**: I load the login page and wait some minutes. Then I fill the username/password and press login button.

So it looks like some sort of timeout. I would like to fix this at the root cause or just catch the exception somehow, to avoid showing this "ugly" error page to the user.

Comment: it sounds to me that this is how it's supposed to work. meaning, the token needs to be refreshed after some time?

Comment: This is intended behaviour, just catch the error and redirect to login, or reload the page so you get a new valid AF token

Comment: @Sean T thanks for your answers. Should I catch the exception server side? What condition should I use on the if on the controller if(condition){ redirect to login} ?